# PHP: Open New Window?

Tags: javascript, php

I understand that JavaScript is client-side and PHP is server-side, within the code below, is there anyway for me to pop up a new window or make a call to pop open a new window? echo statements don't work. Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

```
<?php 

class testpop__class 
{ 
    function testpop__method(&$bean, $event, $arguments=null) 
    { 
        if ($event != 'before_save') return; 
        // Insert your custom logic between these comments 

        // Insert your custom logic between these comments 
    } 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Why should echo statements not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using strictly PHP, no. However, if you use ECHO to output javascript, you can just have javascript open up a new window.

Answer (score 1):

You could use echo to print out some javascript. Like so

```
echo "<script type='javascript'>window.showModalDialog('webpage.php')</script>";
```

Hope this helps.